# How to solve conditional probability of Bayesian network

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-networks

I have the following Bayesian network where I need to solve for Pr(J|C,A,V)

[image]

According to the solutions, Pr(J|C,A,V) = 0.81, but I don't understand how this value was calculated.
If possible, please provide a step by step method:

Answer (score 0):

P(J|AVC) = P(JAVC)/P(AVC)

with

- P(JAVC)=sum_G P(C)P(V)P(A|VC)P(G|AVC)P(J|G) =P(C)P(V)P(A|VC) sum_G P(G|AVC)P(J|G)
- p(AVC) =sum_GJ P(C)P(V)P(A|VC)P(G|AVC)P(J|G) =P(C)P(V)P(A|VC) sum_GJ P(G|AVC)P(J|G)

then

P(J|AVC)=sum_G P(G|AVC)P(J|G) / sum_GJ P(G|AVC)P(J|G)

Using pyAgrum, you can write

```py
f=bn.cpt("G")*bn.cpt("J")
f.margSumOut(["G"])/f.margSumOut(["G","J"])
```

and you obtain

[image]

where you can find 0.81 when every variable is set to 1 (i.e. t)

PS- the definition of the Bayesian network:
[image]